# tmux + putty: Using mouse off window shows junk characters

Tags: putty, tmux

Setup: tmux 1.8 running on Ubuntu 12.04  connecting from Windows with Putty. tmux has mouse mode on.

Steps to reproduce: Select the putty window as active, but use the mouse off the window (i.e in another window) Typically this happens when I am scrolling in another application on another monitor but forgot to switch the mouse focus.Also, this only happens if the putty window is large or maximized.

Issue: Junk commands get dumped into tmux (e.g 7#, H#, 7a etc.)
If I scroll off window with only PuTTY (no tmux) the screen scrolls as expected.

[image: Here's an screenshot of this]

Update: I have determined that this happens if my putty window is has >= 224 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved by Nicholas Marriott - tmux's author - with the patch at http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/tmux-users/thread/20130801222920.GI15241%40yelena.nicm.ath.cx/#msg31242833